# Choose 5 different elements from a list?

Tags: python, arrays, list

What is the best way to choose 5 different elements from a python list and add them to a new list?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: different values or different indexes? In what order - random? Your question is very broad right now.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Assuming that you want them chosen randomly and that `new_list` is already defined,

```
import random

new_list += random.sample(old_list, 5)
```

If `new_list` is not already defined, then you can just do

```
new_list = random.sample(old_list, 5)
```

If you don't want to change `new_list` but want to instead create `new_new_list`, then

```
new_new_list = new_list + random.sample(old_list, 5)
```

Now references to `new_list` will still access a list without the five new elements but `new_new_list` will reference a list with the five elements.

Answer (score 4):

Use `random.sample` call

```
import random
random.sample(yourlist,5)
```

Comment: You had a typo there, but I fixed it. :)

Answer (score 1):

You may need to be more specific, but to return 5 unique elements from your list you can simply use `sample` from the [random module](http://docs.python.org/library/random.html)

```
import random
num = 5
aList = range(30)
newList = []
newList+=random.sample(aList, num)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> list = [1,3,6,3,2,5,7,4,7,8,9,4,3,2,4,6,7]
>>> newlist = []
# Pick 5 and add to new list:
>>> newlist.extend(list[:5])
>>> newlist
[1, 3, 6, 3, 2]
```